# How to read contents of VkBuffer after its being filled with data in Vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

Is there any code snippet to do this?
I am doing an offscreen rendering to a VkImage and want to dump its result to png. I have created a VkBuffer and doing a vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer, but not sure how to move forward.

Edit:
I am creating a VkBuffer with its VkBufferCreateInfo. Not assigning any vkAllocateMemory since I do not want to associate it with any GPU memory. After this I do vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer. So how to do a memcpy assuming the data is copied to VkBuffer.

Comment: So... what's your question? How to read a VkImage's data or how to turn a 2D array of pixels into a PNG?

Comment: @NicolBolas How to read a VkImage data?

Comment: But you *just did* read the image's data. You used `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer`. That's all the "reading" of the data that Vulkan's going to do for you. Are you asking how to read the buffer you just copied the data into? Are you asking how the data in the buffer is stored? Because the Vulkan specification explains both of those. So it's not clear what you're confused on.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes reading the buffer I just copied data into.

Comment: Then *add that* to your question. Use the "edit" button and add in the details. Be as specific as possible.

Comment: "*Not assigning any vkAllocateMemory since I do not want to associate it with any GPU memory.*" Whether you want it or not, that's what you have to do. You cannot execute `vkCmdCopyImageToBuffer` until the buffer has actual memory backing it; the memory region specified in your `pRegions` has to be within the backing storage. And it can't be if there isn't any.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to map the memory of the buffer you copied the data into and pull the data from the `void*`. You **have** to assign memory to the buffer. The memory you'll want to use must be host visible.

If the memory heap you used for the buffer is not coherent then you need to use `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` for the mapped range after the fence is triggered and before you start copying the data out.